Failover Replication Publisher to new version of SQL
We currently have a SQL 2016 availability group where the primary is built on a windows Failover Cluster instance, and want to migrate off of that FCI and onto newer SQL. To complicate things a bit, the primary is also a replication publisher, but with a discrete distribution server (not self-distributing), and there are two read-only asynchronous replicas. All servers are on SQL 2016.
Is it possible to add a 4th synchronous node, failover the primary, and then deprecate the originally primary, without needing to reinitialize (or entirely rebuild) our publications? Or will we have to remove publication, failover, and reconfigure?
